# Access element of list of lists

Tags: python, list

I have some data in the following format that is a list of lists:

```
[[[13', 'Arsenal', '62.9]', '[32', 'Man', 'Utd', '60.9]', '[30', 'Tottenham', '60.7]']],
[[167,Man,City,1,15],[214,Hull,1,12],[29,West,Ham,1,11],]]]
```

I know that if I have a single list (lets assume it is called `var`), I could access elements from `var` using something like:

```
var2 = var[0]
print var2
```

However, I'm not sure how I could code that for the above. I would like the output to be off the format:

```
var1 = 13, Arsenal, 62.9
var2 = 32, Man, Utd, 60.9
var3 = 30, Tottenham, 60.7
var4 = 167, Man, City, 1, 15
var5 = 214 Hull, 1, 12
var 6 = 29, West, Ham, 1, 11
```

Can anyone assist?

Comment: It's `list` of `lists` one option you can use is to `join()` the list cells to one string, Also you have some problems with apostrophe please look carefully at your code.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you have to correct the format of your list, there are wrong apostophes all over the place.
Assuming that you have a list like this:

```
var = [['13', 'Arsenal', '62.9'], ['32', 'Man', 'Utd', '60.9']]
```

a regular print will give you:

```
>>> print var[0]
['13', 'Arsenal', '62.9']
```

If you want a differently formated output, you can use:

```
>>> var1 = ', '.join(var[0])
>>> print var1
13, Arsenal, 62.9
```

Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: hi, thanks for replying. in my example above i would want var to print as: '13', 'Arsenal', '62.9, '32', 'Man', 'Utd', '60.9','30', 'Tottenham', '60.7'

Comment: to get this output but for all items in your list you can use `for i in var` each `i` is a list, then you can do the above to print it out. Eg. `for i in list: print ', '.join(i[0])`